# LINQ: Checking if a string (variable) contains any of the list of properties

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I need to check if my "constant" contains (string) of any items of my collection. My constant is here:

```
  studentTest = "MathsTest"; // THis is a constant that doesn't change,
                                  // it is set on frmLoad
```

Now my linq I require it to see if studentTest contains a string that is in my Tests (collection) with property of Name.

Now the studentTest is always "something" with the "Test" appended to the end i.e MathsTest, EnglishTest etc.

My Tests is a List of "Test", each test has a property called "Name" which has the name of the Test minus the word Test i.e. English , Maths etc  and "NOT" EnglishTest, MathsTest.

So I need to check if my "constant"  -- contains any text which is available in the property "Name" on each test.

I tried playing around here, but I am a little lost and this is the wrong direction.

```
     if ( test.Tests.Any(x => x.Type.Contains(studentTest)) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this; one approach is to remove the "Test" suffix from `studentTest` and search for it:

```
string type = studentTest.substring(0, studentTest.Length - 4);
if (test.Tests.Select(t => t.Type).Contains(type)) { ... }
```

or, if you prefer to use `Any()`:

```
if (test.Tests.Any(t => t.Type == type)) { ... }
```

Actually, the code you showed was almost correct, except that since it is the test name that is a substring of `studentTest`, it should have been

```
if (test.Tests.Any(x => studentTest.Contains(x.Type))) { ... }
```

I would recommend using `Substring()`, though, because the last approach would produce wrong results if one of the test types actually is `"Test"` (very unlikely in your case, though)...

Comment: Yes but it might not always be 4 characters o even the word Test....  I have an idea but i need to test it .... I suppose something like this would work

Comment: if (test.Tests.Any(x => studentTest.Contains(x.Name)))   or maybe not?4

Comment: @Martin: Ah; from your question, it looked like all test names would end in precisely `"Test"`. Then, `Contains()` should work, but I would prefer `StartsWith()`.